# Vuejs2 draggable component with localStorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, vue.js

I am working with some dashboard statistics and need to make divs draggable, so users can drag any chart where they want, for example: replace right or left. And I have done this and work fine, I think. But I want to store this on local storage and I does not know how?

Dashboard cards

```
<template>
  <div class="col-12">
    <d-board id="border-7">
      <d-card id="card-7" draggable="true">
        <p>Card 1</p>
      </d-card>
    </d-board>
  </div>

  <div class="col-12">
    <d-board id="border-8">
      <d-card id="card-8" draggable="true">
        <p>Card 2</p>
      </d-card>
    </d-board>
  </div>
</template>
```

Border

```
<template>
  <div v-if="id" :id="id" class="board" @dragover.prevent @drop.prevent="drop">
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["id"],

  methods: {
    drop: (e) => {
      const card_id = e.dataTransfer.getData("card_id");
      const card = document.getElementById(card_id);

      // card.style.display = "block";
      card.style.opacity = "1";
      e.target.appendChild(card);
      // localStorage.setItem("chart-reorder", e.target.appendChild(card)); 
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

and Cards

```
<template>
    <div :id="id"
        class="draggable-card"
        :draggable="draggable"
        @dragstart="dragStart"
        @dragover.stop
    >
        <slot />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['id', 'draggable'],
        
        methods: {
            dragStart: e => {
                const target = e.target;

                e.dataTransfer.setData('card_id', target.id);

                setTimeout(() => {
                    // target.style.display = "none";
                    target.style.opacity = "0.3";
                }, 0);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

If I use this on `drop` method on bordercomponent it stores data on local storage but not the right way I think

```
localStorage.setItem("chart-reorder", e.target.appendChild(card)); 

//data stored
chart-reorder   [object HTMLDivElement]
```

`ERROR I GOT`

```
card.style.opacity = "1";
      e.target.appendChild(card);
localStorage.setItem("chart-reorder", JSON.stringify(e.target.appendChild(card)));

//ER
app.js:64487 [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'VueComponent'
    |     property '_scope' -> object with constructor 'EffectScope'
    |     property 'effects' -> object with constructor 'Array'
    |     index 0 -> object with constructor 'Watcher'
    --- property 'vm' closes the circle"

TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'VueComponent'
    |     property '_scope' -> object with constructor 'EffectScope'
    |     property 'effects' -> object with constructor 'Array'
    |     index 0 -> object with constructor 'Watcher'
    --- property 'vm' closes the circle
```

`sandbox`
https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-artem-v9xqk3?file=/src/components/draggable/Card.vue

Comment: I don't know how you intend to use the data in localStorage but it needs to be saved as a string, not an object.  use `JSON.stringify(e.target.appendChild(card))` then when you retrieve from localStorage you can use `JSON.parse()` to return the string to an object

Comment: @yoduh  i have tryed to use Json.stringify but show me an errro. And yes i need to call again data from localStorage when i reload page i need to get data from LocalStorage. But also i dont know where i need to calll Json.parse()

Comment: show you how tried to use JSON.stringify and add the error to your question.  `localStorage.setItem("chart-reorder", JSON.stringify(e.target.appendChild(card)));` works just fine for me when I add it to your codesandbox

Comment: @yoduh I tryed to use exactly as on my code snipet, just remove the comment tag. But does show me an error: `[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON` and `app.js:68390 TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON` .. Also i cant see any changes on my sandbox

Comment: @yoduh Please can you do an exmample with my case here? ALso where should i add `localStorage.getItem`?

Comment: I still haven't found a solution for this